# How can I connect to the database and PHPMyAdmin in Delphi 

Tags: delphi, phpmyadmin, delphi-7

I want to make the registration process a user name and password. I use Delphi 7. Component which can be done? (I know very little english, sorry.)

Comment: I've seen much better questions get closed on this site. Voted to close this one because of its overall low quality (i'm not talking about grammar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http request is easiest method (with GET, or POST), but preferred you'll want to use SSL if you dont want passwords/usernames passed along to your webserver un-encrypted.

Example of using POST request:

```
uses
  IdHTTP;

function PostData(const URL: string; Params: TStrings): string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Result := '';
  IdHTTP := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.ReadTimeout := 5000;
    Result := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Params);
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Optionally you can write your own socket, but that will be more difficult because you'll have to write your own listener. (Which is usually not allowed on most shared hosting plans.)

Comment: +1, I've replaced the link (what is always not so good in answer since no one knows how long the target site will be alive) with the code sample. The code from [`the link`](http://codestips.com/delphi-http-post/) is wrong in few things. It never releases `param` and `http` object instances. It uses unecessary `valid` flag variable whilst the result of the function itself might be undefined. Also there is no usage for `on Exception` statement and result is always better pass to the *hidden* `Result` variable instead of passing to the one named as the function itself.

Comment: I created a database. Available for users table.I want to have a registration form from the program? membership registration?